# Angular Update 15 to 16 - Conflicting peer dependency

Tags: angular, npm-install

I'm trying to update an Angular project from Angular version 15 to 16, but I can't make sense of the errors. There seem to be two packages that prevent npm install from running.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!                           
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/cdk@16.1.2                                                          
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@15.2.8                                                                 
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common                                                                  
npm ERR!   peer overridden @angular/common@">15.0.0" (was "^15.0.0") from ng2-pdfjs-viewer@15.0.0      
npm ERR!   node_modules/ng2-pdfjs-viewer                                                               
npm ERR!     ng2-pdfjs-viewer@"15.0.0" from the root project                                           
npm ERR!   peer overridden @angular/common@">9.0.0" (was "^9.1.9") from ng9-password-strength-bar@1.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/ng9-password-strength-bar                                                      
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@16.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from @angular/cdk@16.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!     @angular/cdk@"16.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I also tried npm install and npm update with --legacy-peer-deps, then I get this exception:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find package '@angular/compiler-cli' imported from C:\....\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\load-esm.js
    See "C:\....\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-ekMrvn\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

I'm not sure what to do there and the other solutions I found don't really match this case.
Can anyone give me a suggestion what to do?

Comment: Do you have '@angular/compiler-cli' in the dependencies in your package.json?

Comment: Yes, I have it in my dependencies:     "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.1.2"

Comment: Remove node_modules/ and package.lock.json and try once again. Paste here the out if error still appears.

Answer (score 0):

According to issues in [ng9-password-strength-bar repo](https://github.com/rnadler/ng9-password-strength-bar/issues/8) and [ng2-pdfjs-viewer repo](https://github.com/intbot/ng2-pdfjs-viewer/issues/227), there's no option to update to Angular v16 without using --force.